# Wrong alignment of grids in stackpanel

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, windows, xaml

I do not understand why the alignment of my (generated) XAML code is wrong.

XAML:

```
<ScrollViewer>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">

            <HeaderedContentControl Header="innerer Ex-Schutz Anforderung">
                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="5"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="5"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="5"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="5"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="5"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="48"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <Rectangle Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,0,2,0" Stretch="Fill" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" StrokeThickness="0" Stroke="Transparent" Fill ="#FFFFFF88"/>
                        <TextBlock Margin="5" Grid.Column="0" Text="IX02"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,5,0" Text="Ex-Zone"/>
                        <mvvmui:VmpEditor Grid.Column="2" DataContext="{Binding Data[This][]}" ShowCaption="False" WrapReadOnlyText="True"/>
                    </Grid>

                    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="5" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="48"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <Rectangle Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,0,2,0" Stretch="Fill" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" StrokeThickness="0" Stroke="Transparent" Fill ="#FFFFFF88"/>
                        <TextBlock Margin="5" Grid.Column="0" Text="IX04"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,5,0" Text="Ex-Gruppe"/>
                        <mvvmui:VmpEditor Grid.Column="2" DataContext="{Binding Data[This][0173-1---ADVANCED_1_1#01-ADN507#007/0173-1#01-ADR534#007/0173-1#02-AAR158#007/0173-1#02-AAR159#005/0173-1#02-AAQ920#005/0173-1#02-AAO370#004]}" ShowCaption="False" WrapReadOnlyText="True"/>
                    </Grid>

                    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="48"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <Rectangle Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,0,2,0" Stretch="Fill" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" StrokeThickness="0" Stroke="Transparent" Fill ="#FFFFFF88"/>
                        <TextBlock Margin="5" Grid.Column="0" Text="IX06"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,5,0" Text="Temp.klasse"/>
                        <mvvmui:VmpEditor Grid.Column="2" DataContext="{Binding Data[This][0173-1---ADVANCED_1_1#01-ADN507#007/0173-1#01-ADR534#007/0173-1#02-AAR158#007/0173-1#02-AAR159#005/0173-1#02-AAQ920#005/0173-1#02-AAO371#004]}" ShowCaption="False" WrapReadOnlyText="True"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </HeaderedContentControl>

            <HeaderedContentControl Header="äußerer Ex-Schutz Anforderung">
                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="5"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="5"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="5"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="5"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="5"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="48"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <Rectangle Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,0,2,0" Stretch="Fill" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" StrokeThickness="0" Stroke="Transparent" Fill ="#FFFFFF88"/>
                        <TextBlock Margin="5" Grid.Column="0" Text="AX02"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,5,0" Text="Ex-Zone Umgebung"/>
                        <mvvmui:VmpEditor Grid.Column="2" DataContext="{Binding Data[CboProcessConnection].PropertyList[EPROutsideZone]}" ShowCaption="False" WrapReadOnlyText="True"/>
                    </Grid>

                    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="5" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="48"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <Rectangle Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,0,2,0" Stretch="Fill" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" StrokeThickness="0" Stroke="Transparent" Fill ="#FFFFFF88"/>
                        <TextBlock Margin="5" Grid.Column="0" Text="AX04"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,5,0" Text="Ex-Gruppe Umgebung"/>
                        <mvvmui:VmpEditor Grid.Column="2" DataContext="{Binding Data[CboProcessConnection].PropertyList[EPROutsideGroup]}" ShowCaption="False" WrapReadOnlyText="True"/>
                    </Grid>

                    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="48"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <Rectangle Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,0,2,0" Stretch="Fill" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" StrokeThickness="0" Stroke="Transparent" Fill ="#FFFFFF88"/>
                        <TextBlock Margin="5" Grid.Column="0" Text="AX06"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,5,0" Text="Temperaturklasse Umgebung"/>
                        <mvvmui:VmpEditor Grid.Column="2" DataContext="{Binding Data[CboProcessConnection].PropertyList[EPROutsideTempClass]}" ShowCaption="False" WrapReadOnlyText="True"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </HeaderedContentControl>
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

Here you can the the result:

[image]

Its not easy to see but the two yellow boxes on the right side should be exactly under each other. But the lower is a few pixels to the right.

Does anyone understand that?

Interestingly, when you enter a fixed width to the StackPanel (say, 1500), it works. But I do not want a fixed width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’ve got auto-width columns in separate grids. If you want columns in two different grids to be the same width, you have three options:

1. Fixed size. That’s lame and you don’t want it.
2. Put everything in one big grid.
3. Put `Grid.IsSharedSizeScope=“True”` on some common parent element of both grids, and add `SharedSizeGroup=“SomeArbitaryName”` on the autosized columns that are sizing slightly differently in the two different child grids, and which are positioning the third columns differently as a result (that’s the first column in each). This is the best solution in your case, I believe.

Comment: 1. The error also occurs with non fixed size
2. Single blocks can have between 2 and 4 columns (we don't know it before). Because of this we can't take a grid.

Comment: @SimonHilner I told you know to make children of disparate parents dynamically align with each other. This is done with a Grid with shared size groups. If that’s not the problem you’re actually having, ask a new question. This is basic, trivial WPF layout.